# Swift Segment Controller getting nil on UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

So i have been working on this app.I pass information from a list to this "Show Exercise" View where the informations will load.

**The List 1:**

[image]

When I click on it it sends me to the Show Exercise View where the Segment View is located

**The Show Exercise View:**

[image]

I was using views here and when I assign classes to them or if i assign the class "ShowExerciseViewController" which is the main Class I'm getting errors on

```
VideoContainer.hidden = false .....
```

I have tried to comment them our and it works than when i connect everything and try to assign value to it it stops and tells me its nil.
Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
```

class ShowExerciseViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var VideoContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet var MusclesContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet var InstructionsContainer: UIView!


@IBOutlet var holder_description: UITextView!

var _id_:String = ""

var _Decider = Decider()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    VideoContainer.hidden = false
    MusclesContainer.hidden = true
    InstructionsContainer.hidden = true
    self.title = _Decider.name_decider(_id_)
    //holder_description.text = "Placeholder"
    //print(_Decider.description_decider(_id_))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func segmentControllerAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0:
        VideoContainer.hidden = false
        MusclesContainer.hidden = true
        InstructionsContainer.hidden = true
        break
    case 1:
        MusclesContainer.hidden = false
        VideoContainer.hidden = true
        InstructionsContainer.hidden = true
        break
    case 2:
        InstructionsContainer.hidden = false
        MusclesContainer.hidden = true
        VideoContainer.hidden = true
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Story Board:

[image]

Comment: It works with the code above,thats not the problem.

Comment: The problem is that i cant connect mu UIImage views and the rest and assign value to them.I have no idea how it keeps crashing or giving me nil

Comment: No this code above is working ok its like this.The code is working which is above writen.Now somehow i need to assign values that i get from my ShowExercise view to the UIView UILabels etc.The problem is i dont know how to do it.I have tried to assign the same class to the UIViews but not working,or to create another class and to assign value but it gives me nil when i give to my UI elements information.So i need from that code above to make a connection to my UI Elements.

Comment: Dude no its not that.Ok nevermind

Comment: If you don't know and undarstand don't answer

Comment: I need ShowExerciseViewController to link to the other 3 view controller but it's not working with it